# FFmpeg add proxy to request

Tags: ffmpeg

Does FFmpeg support the ability to add a proxy to a request? On the Internet, I found that there is the -http_proxy option, but when I tried to use it by typing `ffmpeg -http_proxy=http://ip:port/` in terminal, I received an Option not found error

Comment: Use space, not equal sign.

Comment: @Gyan  Unable to find a suitable output format for 'http_proxy'
http_proxy: Invalid argument

Comment: @Gyan Maybe you can show full ffmpeg requst with http_proxy?

Comment: What's your full command?

Comment: @Gyan only `ffmpeg http_proxy http://136.243.47.220:3128` Or should I write a complete request in terminal? Also, for ffmpeg I u se Java wrapper - ffmpeg-cli-wrapper.  Here is his request, without proxy `ffmpeg.exe -y -v error -progress tcp://127.0.0.1:36512 tcp://136.243.47.220:3128 -i https://animethemes.moe/video/HeavyObject-ED2v2.webm stuff/WEBMs/Kawaranai Tsuyosa.opus`

Comment: `ffmpeg.exe -y -v error -progress tcp://127.0.0.1:36512 -http_proxy http://ip:port/ -i https://animethemes.moe/video/HeavyObject-ED2v2.webm stuff/WEBMs/Kawaranai Tsuyosa.opus tcp://136.243.47.220:3128`

Comment: `ffmpeg.exe -y -v error -progress tcp://127.0.0.1:37076 -http_proxy http://136.243.47.220:3128/ -i https://animethemes.moe/video/HeavyObject-ED2v2.webm stuff/WEBMs/Kawaranai Tsuyosa.opus`
Unrecognized option 'http_proxy http://136.243.47.220:3128/'.

Comment: @Gyan No ideas?

Comment: What's your ffmpeg version?

Comment: @Gyan `ffmpeg version N-94528-gfaa9cd312f Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers`

Comment: Add -report and share report.

Comment: @Gyan https://hasteb.in/wetucuqe.bash

Comment: Don't quote the option or arg.

Comment: @Gyan `ffmpeg.exe -y -v error -progress tcp://127.0.0.1:40293 -http_proxy http://51.254.69.246:3128/ -i https://animethemes.moe/video/HeavyObject-ED2v2.webm stuff/WEBMs/Kawaranai Tsuyosa.opus`
[tcp @ 000001f59c6aa780] Connection to tcp://127.0.0.1:40293 failed: Error number -138 occurred
Failed to open progress URL "tcp://127.0.0.1:40293": Error number -138 occurred
Failed to set value 'tcp://127.0.0.1:40293' for option 'progress': Error number -138 occurred
Error parsing global options: Error number -138 occurred

Comment: Write progress to a local file.Anyway, this is a different issue.

Comment: @Gyan Thank you!! It helped. If you want, you can write your answer and I will mark it true.
Also, so that the wrapper does not highlight -http proxy, you must write -http proxy and ip:port in separate additional arguments

Comment: @Gyan Do ffmpeg proxies works at all? Because I specifically banned my ip on the site to test proxies and when trying `ffmpeg.exe -y -v error tcp://127.0.0.1:29046 -http_proxy http://91.67.17.221:3128/ -i https://animethemes.moe/video/HangyakuseiMillionArthur-OP1.webm stuff/WEBMs/Highlight.opus` I got a _Server returned 4XX Client Error_. Also, if i change my ip, all works

Answer (score 5):

So, as the comments explained to me, I was just doing the request incorrectly. FFmpeg supports proxies, just write `-http_proxy http://ip:port/` Be sure not to select it by "". Also, if you use Java wrapper *ffmpeg-cli-wrapper*, then separate the proxy flag (-http_proxy) and the proxies themselves into two different `addExtraArgs`,
otherwise an error will be causing

Comment: Did you succeed connect through http proxy? What is your FFmpeg version?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on Windows 10, but with the extra environment variable (explained here:  [Set proxy through windows command line including login parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992886/set-proxy-through-windows-command-line-including-login-parameters) ), without any extra command line parameter for ffmpeg:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://yourproxyservername:yourproxyserverport
ffmpeg.exe -codec copy download.mp4 -i "https://mediaserver/transform/videomanifest"
```